# Правильно ли будет скрывать информацию в футере?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Я вижу, как другие сайты скрывают информацию в хедере, но в футере делают адаптив. Заказчик сказал постепенно скрывать информацию в header. В footer также скрывать или переносить всё это в колонки, делать `flex-wrap: wrap` и т.д.? Как бы вы сделали?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы не можете наперед создать структуру при которой вы просто разместите блоки вертикально, попробуйте скрывать блок с нужной разметкой для больших устройств и попробуйте показывать блок с мобильной разметкой на маленьких устройствах. Создайте контейнер в котором будет необходимая разметка, сделайте проверку через медиа запрос и скройте элемент, создайте такой же контейнер но с другом разметкой в нужной структуре и покажите данный элемент через медиа запрос на нужных устройствах. Это самый легкий способ для решения вашего вопроса. Либо нужно создавать адаптивную структуру и все продумывать

Answer (score 0):

Скрытие информации в хедере при адаптивной верстке делают для того, чтобы пользователю не пришлось скроллить несколько экранов бесполезную часть (а хедер в принципе бесполезен, нужен только гамбургер и заголовок текущей страницы).

Футер обычно делают вертикальный одноколоночный и не скрывают информацию, т.к. если она пользователю неинтересна, то он просто не будет скроллить вниз, а если интересна, то все равно раскроет и проскроллит.

Просто когда что-то делаете, представьте себе, что юзер - жуткий лентяй и его бесит КАЖДОЕ лишнее телодвижение. Лишний скроллинг до контента, лишнее раскрытие после, выпадающий список вместо трех радиокнопок, пользование клавиатурой вместо мыши...